# How to convert DSA Keystore certificate to RSA?

Tags: java, android, react-native, keystore

I have an React Native application in store signed with a keystore generated with **java 8**.
The key algorithm is **DSA**.
I switched to **Java 11** (because I upgraded React Native...).
I can't generate APK because Java 11 use RSA algorithm and does not support DSA.

I know that we can't convert **DSA** certificate to **RSA**. But is there another way ? Like renewing certificate after extracting it from the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

More or less like this.
It seems to me that you cannot convert an existing certificate because it has already been issued and signed by your issuer. The signature of the issuer makes it immutable.

Subject: CN=Pamella Hendrixen, OU=IM, O=UoK, L=Welaniya, ST=WP, C=LK
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withDSA, OID = 2.16.840.1.101.3....